# How to implement Dagger for worker classes in Dagger 2.16 ?('android.arch.work:work-runtime')

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-workmanager

How to implement Dagger for worker classes in Dagger 2.16?

```
public class SyncWorker extends  Worker {

    @Inject
    ISettingRepository settingRepository;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        sync();
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    private void sync() {

    }
}
```

my AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        BaseModule.class,
        ApiModule.class,
        UserDatabaseModule.class,
        SaleDatabaseModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        ActivityBuilderModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {
    void inject(BaseApp app);

    @Override
    void inject(DaggerApplication application);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance

        Builder getApp(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

}
```

How can I inject the settingRepository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to inject a worker with this approach.

1. First, create a new method inside your app component that will inject your worker class.

   ```
   @Singleton
   public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<YourApplicationClass> {

       @Component.Builder
       interface Builder {

           @BindsInstance
           AppComponent.Builder application(Application application);

           AppComponent build();
       }

       void inject(NotifWorker worker);
   }
   ```
2. Inside your application, build your dagger component as usual but assign it to a variable and make it global.

   ```
   public class YourApplicationClass implements HasActivityInjector {

     private AppComponent appComponent;
     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();

         appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                 .application(this)
                 .build();

         appComponent.inject(this);
     }

     public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
         return appComponent;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Inside your worker class, do something like this.

   ```
   public class NotifWorker extends Worker {

     @Inject
     ToBeInjectedClass toBeInjectedClass;

     public NotifWorker() {
       YourApplicationClass
           .getInstance()
           .getAppComponent()
           .inject(this)
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't do this, at least use getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 3):

To inject any classes in Dagger 2, you have to first provide those classes using `@provides` annotation in the module.

You have to first create a component containing a module which provides the desired class.

Example:-

```
@component(modules = {Module1.class})
public interface Component1{

void inject(SyncWorker syncWorker);
}

@Module
public class Module1{

@Provides
public ISettingRepository getSettingRepo(){
  return new ISettingRepository();
}

}
```

Now write in your code, a constructor that is used to inject the component into your worker class.

```
public class SyncWorker extends  Worker {

    @Inject
    ISettingRepository settingRepository;

    public SyncWorker(){
       DaggerComponent1.builder().build().inject(this);
     }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        sync();
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    private void sync() {

    }
}
```

Now when the constructor runs, your settingRepository instance would be initialized.

Comment: I changed the text of the question.

Comment: In my case, the contractor did not work in my Worker, I put injector in doWork and it is fine